# NASM _printf function is not working after the memory access code

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

## Problem Situation

I am writing a code that puts a value in memory and moves it to eax register to print.
But _printf function is not working at all, there is no error and just nothing is shown on the screen.

This is the code.

```
section .data
   msg db "%d", 10, 0

section .text
   extern _printf
   global _main

_main:
   push ebp
   mov ebp, esp

   mov byte [402000], 100
   mov eax, dword [402000]

   push eax
   push msg
   call _printf

   leave
   ret
```

and I compiled with these three lines of command

```
nasm -f win32 memory.asm
gcc memory.obj
```

I executed the exe file, it is the result

NOTHING

Nothing is printed on the screen. No error, no warning, but nothing is shown on the screen

## Problem Cause

I can't know the cause of this problem exactly. That's why I posted this question. But I thought about many reasons.

I'm guessing, it can be divided into three cases.

1. Problem of _print function call process
2. Problem with moving value to memory
3. Problem with moving value of memory to eax

### Problem of _print function call process

I checked that it is not the problem of printing part. If I just move 100 to the eax and print it out, 100 is printed well.

```
mov eax, 100

push eax
push msg
call _printf
```

```
100
```

### Problem with moving value to memory

I don't think there is a problem with this.

This works without error and 100 is acceptable for byte size.

### Problem with moving value of memory to eax

There might be a problem in this part.

Because I have always done like this when I move the value to eax, but it is my first time putting the value of memory into it. I wrote this code just by intuition without searching on the Internet. So, the form of this instruction may be wrong.

## What I Want

```
[402000] <- 100
eax <- [402000]
print eax

and as a result

100
```

Put 100 in [402000], put the value to the eax, and print 100 by printing eax.
It is the result that I want.

Thanks.

Comment: (1) Why do you think that `402000` is an accessible address that you can freely write to?  (2) You are storing a byte there and then loading back a dword, so even if it works, the upper 24 bits of the number loaded into `eax` will be garbage.

Comment: @NateEldredge The `leave` instruction cleans up the stack by setting `esp` to `ebp`

Comment: @TimothyBaldwin: Oh, you're right.  Still a possible pitfall if that weren't the last thing in your function.

Comment: Probably you're just crashing on memory access to `402000`.  No reason to expect the containing page to be mapped at all, let alone writeable.  Remember that's decimal, not hex, and you're making a Windows executable.  (`0x402000` is a typical data-section address on x86-64 GNU/Linux for non-PIE executables, but this is a 32-bit Windows target so I assume the default linker script doesn't choose `0x402000`, let alone `402000`.  Also, I just checked `readelf -a` on a non-PIE executable I built recent on Linux and the `.text` section was getting mapped read-only at `0x402000`, not .data.)

Comment: IDK why Windows or your shell wouldn't report the program crashed, assuming that's what's happening.  Under GNU/Linux, a command shell like bash would reliably report that the child process segfaulted.  You could try cygwin or mingw bash.

Comment: @PeterCordes thx for answering. but nothing is shown on the screen even though i used mingw bash.

Comment: Maybe use a debugger, then.  It should definitely report of the process being debugged triggers a fault.  You could also try `mov [0xffffffff], eax` to almost certainly fault by touching unmapped memory (1 byte at the top of memory, and 3 bytes at the bottom because the dword store wraps around).  If that produces the same behaviour (silent exit), then you know for sure you need to fix your dev environment so you can see when your programs crash.  Or `mov [_main], eax` should also fault; hopefully code will be in a read-only page.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer!

[402000] is not an address that I can access and update freely.

I changed the memory address. This shows the result that I wanted.

code:

```
section .data
   msg db "%d", 10, 0

section .text
   extern _printf
   global _main

_main:
   push ebp
   mov ebp, esp

   mov byte [100000], 100
   mov eax, dword [100000]

   push eax
   push msg
   call _printf

   leave
   ret
```

result:

```
100
```

idk why I was so embarrassed by such an easy question.

Now I will find out the range of memory that is freely accessible in my system.

Thank you to everyone who helped. Special thanks to Peter Cordes and Nate Eldredge.

**P.S.**

it is not a perfect solution. It may not be safe to access random address,
because some functions can use that memory.

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to write to some arbitrary numeric address you just made up.  Something else might be using it.  e.g. `printf` might use some data structures there!  (Since it works in your case, that problem didn't happen in this case).  It's the exact same reason that in C we call `malloc()` or declare a static array (e.g. `resb` in the BSS section in asm) when we want a pointer to some new memory, not just `char *mem = (char*)100000;` `*mem = 100;`.  That's what you're doing in asm, and it's just as unsafe as in C.  So yes, right problem, bad solution.

Comment: @PeterCordes well, I think it's a matter to think about for safety. I'll keep searching for good solutions.